# Convert n-dimensional numpy array into torch tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, tensor, numpy-ndarray

I have 4-dimensional numpy array (`type(x)` is `ndarray`, `type(x[i])` is `ndarray`, `type(x[i][j])` is `ndarray`, and `type(x[i][j][k])` is `float32`). I need to convert it to torch tensor to use it as part of dataset. I tried to stack `torch.Tensor` like that:

```
def convert_to_tensor(ndarr):
    for i in ndarr:
        for j in ndarr[i]:
            tensor_ndarr = torch.stack([torch.Tensor(k) for k in ndarr[i][j]])
    return tensor_ndarr
```

but not sure if that gonna work.
Is there more simple or convenient way to do that?

P.S. X looks like that:

```
[array([[0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, ..., 9.1042261e-07,
        4.2489510e-06, 1.0829879e-07],
       [0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, ..., 4.5446509e-06,
        1.0727225e-05, 7.5697239e-06],
       [0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, ..., 1.4139889e-06,
        8.1363060e-06, 5.8842788e-06],
       ...,
       [0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, ..., 1.2733157e-07,
        3.6470925e-07, 2.5473477e-07],
       [0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, ..., 7.2166131e-08,
        2.0409759e-07, 2.3035474e-07],
       [0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, ..., 5.7966993e-08,
        1.7371592e-07, 1.5426794e-07]], dtype=float32)
...
 array([[0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, ..., 9.1042261e-07,
        4.2489510e-06, 1.0829879e-07],
       [0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, ..., 4.5446509e-06,
        1.0727225e-05, 7.5697239e-06],
       [0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, ..., 1.4139889e-06,
        8.1363060e-06, 5.8842788e-06],
       ...,
       [0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, ..., 1.2733157e-07,
        3.6470925e-07, 2.5473477e-07],
       [0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, ..., 7.2166131e-08,
        2.0409759e-07, 2.3035474e-07],
       [0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, ..., 5.7966993e-08,
        1.7371592e-07, 1.5426794e-07]], dtype=float32)]
```

Comment: Did you try `torch.from_numpy` method?

Comment: @mcemilg Yes, it gives me `TypeError: can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.object_. The only supported types are: float64, float32, float16, int64, int32, int16, int8, uint8, and bool.`

Comment: So the elements not `float32`. Convert them to `float32` before creating tensor. Try it `arr.astype('float32')` to convert them.

Comment: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` is thrown.

Comment: Make sure your arrays are in same lengths and the elements are in same types.